# What does jQuery html( ) returns?

Tags: jquery

i have seen the code below which is interesting to me:

```
var target = $('#target');
target.html(target.html().replace(/h2/g,'h3'));
```

i'm wondering html( ) return the html content of that element, why it can use .replace( ) method of javascript String?

Comment: from your code it will replace h2 with h3, you should try and check output

Comment: Your code should work. What errors do you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained quite clearly in [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/html/), called with no arguments it returns the html content *as a string...* (What else would html be?)

As an aside, rather than nesting a call to *.html()* inside another, to do a replacement on the same element(s) you can do this:

```
$("#target").html(function(i, h) { return h.replace(/h2/g, "h3"); });
```

Comment: Even if we pass the argument, it returns the new html in an array. +1 for nice answer.

Comment: @Exception - no, if you pass an argument to _.html()_ (whether a string or a function), it returns the same jQuery object it was called on. Which isn't an array, it's an array-like object containing references to DOM elements, not html.

Comment: yes, it is returning selectors list where `html()` is used. I apologise for my mistake. I have got the same result as you but looking at the `html` in returned selector list array I understood wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It can use the replace method because .html returns html as a string.

See http://api.jquery.com/html/ for more.

Answer (score 0):

html can get or set the contents of an object. http://api.jquery.com/html/

The outer call is setting the content using the inner paramaterless call to retrieve the initial html content as a string on which it calls replace.